# Flask/SQLalchemy login authoritarian

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I have some issues with Flask login authorization. I cant figure out what I am doing wrong. Help is very much appreciated. I hope the provided code is enough to figure out what's going on.

Thank you!

User model: user.py

```
class User(UserMixin,db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True
    )
    username = db.Column(db.String)
    password = db.Column(
        db.String,
        nullable=False
    )
    center_id = db.Column(
        db.String
    )
    
    added = db.Column(
        db.Date,
        server_default=func.now()
    )
```

**login_management.py**

```
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt

login_manager = LoginManager()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()


login_manager.login_view = "auth.login"
login_manager.refresh_view = 'auth.login'
login_manager.session_protection = 'strong'
login_manager.needs_refresh_message = (
    u"Please log in again to view that page."
)
login_manager.needs_refresh_message_category = "bg-warning"
```

****init**.py**

```
...
from ..auth import login_manager, bcrypt 
from .models import User

create_app(config):
  ...
  db.init_app(app)
  db.create_all()
  login_manager.init_app(app)

# import and register blueprints
...

login_manager.user_loader
    def user_loader(user_id):
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))
        #return User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()
```

i tryed to get the user with User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first() with an similar result

**auth\routhes.py**

```
from flask import current_app
from flask import render_template
from flask import redirect
from flask import session
from flask import flash
from flask import abort
from flask import request
from flask import url_for

from flask_login import login_user
from flask_login import logout_user
from flask_login import login_required
from flask_login import login_fresh
from flask_login import current_user
from flask_login import confirm_login

from urllib.parse import urlparse, urljoin

import click
from .bp import bp
from .login_management import login_manager, bcrypt
from ..models import User
from datetime import datetime, timedelta



@login_manager.unauthorized_handler
def unauthorized():
    flash("You must be logged in to view that page.","bg-danger")
    
    #If the user is logged in, redirect them to their default page
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect_by_role("ADMIN")

    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

@bp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    # Don't make users log in again if their session is fresh
    click.secho(f"current_user: {type(current_user)}", fg="yellow", bold=True)
    if current_user.is_authenticated and login_fresh():
            return redirect(url_for('messanger.messanger'))
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = User.query.filter_by(username = request.form.get('username').lower()).first()
        user_pw = request.form.get('password')
        check_pw = bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, user_pw)
        if user is not None and check_pw:
            login_user(user)
            session.partition = True
            flash(f"Welcome back, {user.username}!", "bg-success")
            # Determine whether their next URL is safe
            next = request.args.get('next')
            if not is_safe_url(next):
                return about(400)
            return redirect(url_for('admin.users.manage'))
        else:
            flash("Username or password is incorrect.", "bg-danger")
    return render_template('login.html')


@bp.route('/reauth', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reauth():
    """Makes a user log back in to refresh session.
    """

    # Check if the login is fresh
    if not login_fresh():
        if request.method == "POST":

            # Try to find the user reauthenticating
            user = User.query.filter_by(
                username=request.form.get('username').lower()).first()
            # If the user exists, check if their password is correct
            if (
                user is not None
                and bcrypt.check_password_hash(
                        user.password, request.form['password']
                    )
            ):
                # Relogin the user
                confirm_login()

                flash(f"Thank you for reauthenticating, {user.username}!", "bg-success")

                # Determine whether their next URL is safe
                next = request.args.get('next')
                if not is_safe_url(next):
                    return abort(400)

                return redirect(url_for('admin.users.manage'))
            else:
                flash("Username or password is incorrect.", "bg-danger")

        return render_template('auth/login.html')

    return redirect(request.args.get('next') or redirect(url_for("test.test"))

@bp.route('/logout', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def logout():
    """Logs out the current user.
    """
    if current_user:
        logout_user()
        flash("Logged out.", "bg-success")
    return redirect(url_for("auth.login"))



def is_safe_url(target):
    """ Determines whether a URL is safe to navigate to.
        
        Args:
        -----
        target : The target URL

        Returns:
        --------
        bool
    """
    accepted_schemes = ('https')
    if type(current_app.config).__name__ != "ProductionConfig":
        accepted_schemes = ('https','http')

    ref_url = urlparse(request.host_url)
    test_url = urlparse(urljoin(request.host_url, target))
    return test_url.scheme in accepted_schemes and \
            ref_url.netloc == test_url.netloc
```

**ERROR_MESSAGE CHROME**

```
ValueError
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x01'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "..\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2088, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "..\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "..\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "..\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "..\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "..\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
File ..\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 270, in decorated_view
elif not current_user.is_authenticated:
File ..\venv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 422, in __get__
obj = instance._get_current_object()
File "..\venv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 544, in _get_current_object
return self.__local()  # type: ignore
File "..\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 26, in <lambda>
current_user = LocalProxy(lambda: _get_user())
File "..\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 346, in _get_user
current_app.login_manager._load_user()
File "..\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_login\login_manager.py", line 318, in _load_user
user = self._user_callback(user_id)
File ..\medichat\app_factory\__init__.py", line 61, in user_loader
return User.query.get(int(user_id))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x01'
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

dump() shows all variables in the frame
dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object
Brought to you by DON'T PANIC, your friendly Werkzeug powered traceback interpreter.
```

**UPDATE:**

2nd User - same Issue

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(user_id):
    
    print(User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first())
```

I tried to return the User with filter_by.

New error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for type integer: ""
LINE 3: WHERE "user".id = '' 
                          ^

[SQL: SELECT "user".id AS user_id, "user".username AS user_username, "user".password AS user_password, "user".center_id AS user_center_id, "user".added AS user_added 
FROM "user" 
WHERE "user".id = %(id_1)s 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s]
[parameters: {'id_1': '\x02', 'param_1': 1}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/9h9h)
```

Comment: it seems like the id stored on the database is broken
could you please try creating a new user and then try to login?

Comment: sadly same result :(

Comment: maybe try `filter_by(id=int(user_id))`, cause flask-login passes the parameter as a unicode, so the type conversion might work

Comment: Is this because Flask-Login now requires the `user.id` to be a `str` instead of an `int`?